# How to find out error if is not raised in C# in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

After few hours I get this error. I am running program in debugging mode but does not show error. How can I get error why program is stopped. Any ideas? I am using C# and VS 2010.

Translations:

because of the errors program was closed. Windows will close and notify you about the solution.

And two buttons. Search and Close. But search button does not help.

EDIT:

Error in Event logs

Misnomer program: NCrawler.Demo.exe, version: 3.0.0.0, timestamp: 0x52bb34d2 Wrong module name: libcef.DLL, version: 3.1650.1544.0, timestamp: 0x52a42238 Code exceptions: 0xc0000005

Comment: Lost in translation.....

Comment: What does your error box say in English?

Comment: Is your app multithreaded?

Comment: Sorry I added translations. Yes it is multithreaded.

Comment: You can look in the Windows Application Event Logs to see if anything was entered there.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your code and stepping into as the program runs?

Comment: @Mark in event log is: Misnomer program: NCrawler.Demo.exe, version: 3.0.0.0, timestamp: 0x52bb34d2
Wrong module name: libcef.DLL, version: 3.1650.1544.0, timestamp: 0x52a42238
Code exceptions: 0xc0000005

Comment: @Tim breakpoint does not help...

Comment: Did you enable under `Debug` => `Exceptions` to break when unhandled exceptions are thrown? Maybe that might help.

Comment: @Gorgsenegger yes all under "Thrown"

Answer (score 1):

I use [NBug](http://nbug.codeplex.com/) to catch such behaviour. It collectes all exceptions unhandled by code and close it in zip file with detailed XML description and minidump.

Comment: I tried but it is not logged. This error is not logged. Actually I didn't get any log filebut i set to save it in file...